# Problem with Settings app

Tags: iphone, plist, settings.bundle

I'm learning to write a settings application in iPhone. I add items and subnodes to those items in the root property list. When I open Settings I can see my app setting there but not all the items are reflected to the settings. I can get a text field with title Username.But I can't get a textfield for password, all I get is a textfield, it's not secure, so anything I write in that  field is not displayed as stars.Here's whar I write:

```
items2      dictionary
  type      string     PSTextFieldSpecifier
  isSecure  Boolean    YES
  title     string     Password
  key       string     password
```

And I can't see anything else I've saved in the plist. I compare the plist in the study book I follow and the one I have They're exactly the same. If I Build and Run the project provided by the book, it's ok, all the settings are there. Is there a special consideration with Settings App?

[Here's the link to the plist](http://www.mediafire.com/?ny8jbwdmh2z1s7x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't `isSecure` be `YES`?

Comment: Can you provide the `plist` file you are using? And have you tried cleaning your build?

Comment: No i have not tried cleaning the build. Why should I? Here's the link to the plist.   http://www.mediafire.com/?ny8jbwdmh2z1s7x

Comment: I have tried your `root.plist` file and it is working fine for me. You should do `Product` > `Clean` just in case.

Comment: Try [`this`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/MikSettings.zip) and let me know if the same `root.plist` file doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you. I made a Clean and it worked surprisingly. But I really don't understand what could cause a fresh project not work properly and need to be cleaned.

Comment: Hard to tell since you say it's a new project.